# non readable POM {path} input contain no data

Tags: java, maven

I am new to Maven. I'm learning it using some books, and when I try to run this in PowerShell:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=net.sirirangan.packt.maven -DartifactId=MySampleApp
```

I get this error:

> Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>   [FATAL] Non-readable POM F:\tt\pom.xml: input contained no data

Even if I execute this: `mvn help:effective-pom`,  I get the same error.
What I did is created an empty `pom.xml` in `tt` folder and I went to that folder in PowerShell and executed the command.

Answer (score 1):

Maven archetypes are made to generate you projects from scratch; you should have nothing set up before running one.  So, you shouldn't have any POM around, empty or otherwise.

There are tons of different archetypes; they are project templates basically.  So, you can have an archetype generate you a basic application, or one that generates you a complex web-app with Spring MVC and JPA (for database interactions) in it already.

From this link: https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/

Here is a sample archetype generate command for the quickstart archetype (just a basic maven java project one).

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.3
```

Note that I added a new line with a \ to make it more readable; you should just take that out and combine the lines as they had in the link.

It looks like you're missing the `archetypeArtifactId`.  What archetype were you trying to use?

**Extra Suggestions**

Create a nested sub directory and make sure you can create a file there.  Then run the generate command from in the directory.

Here's a demonsration of it on my PC:

**To Demonstrate**

Using Maven version 3.3.3:

```
> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.3
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0-alpha-1 -> http://10.48.82.139/ETCB/nexus/content/groups/fid] found in catalog remote
Define value for property 'groupId': my.group
Define value for property 'artifactId': my-project
Define value for property 'version' 1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for property 'package' my.group: :
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: my.group
artifactId: my-project
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: my.group
 Y: : Y
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart:1.3
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: my.group
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: my-project
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: my.group
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: my/group
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: my.group
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: my.group
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: my-project
[INFO] Project created from Archetype in dir: C:\Dev\git\archetype-test\my-project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:17 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-07T14:11:07-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/491M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I already tried that, it gives me this error: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (F:\tt). Pl
ease verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory

Comment: Added some more info and output from an example of me running it just now.

Comment: i executed the line you gave me this error:   
 The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (F:\tt\ww). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory

Comment: if I execute this alone it works : mvn archetype:generate

Comment: Sorry, not sure what to say.  I ran it in an empty directory... definitely no project around (that’s the point, it creates one).

Comment: thank you for trying anyway, which makes me crazy is that it works if i run this: mvn archetype:generate

Comment: FYI, most people run this from an IDE.  Try getting IntelliJ community edition.  File, new project, maven, select create from archetype, and pick the quick start one.  It comes bundled with its own maven, so that should be set up properly.  Try that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your M2_HOME is set to invalid version. Just remove it or correct the path and try again.